# Html with thymeleaf list

Tags: html, thymeleaf

I have code like this:

```
<ul th:each="pet : ${petCollection}">
    <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in
        <button class="badge" onclick="window.location.href='/'">Continue</button>
        <button type="submit" class="badge">Info</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

its displays like this:

[image]

but I dont want static content inside my list so im adding this:

```
<ul th:each="pet : ${petCollection}">
    <li class="list-group-item" th:text="${pet.petName}">Dapibus ac facilisis in
        <button class="badge" onclick="window.location.href='/'">Continue</button>
        <button type="submit" class="badge">Info</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

but then Im getting this:

[image]

long story short, **the buttons are missing**, any idea guys how I could solve it?

Comment: it is a good question, could you maybe also add the backend implementation for others who came across with a similar question? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you add *th:text* to an element, it replaces the entire contents of that element -- in your case, this is overwriting the `<button />` tags with the pet name. To fix this, you want to put the *th:text* in another tag of it's own, so that the rest of the tags aren't affected. Something like this:

```
<ul  th:each="pet : ${petCollection}">
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <span th:text="${pet.petName}">Dapibus ac facilisis in</span>
    <button class="badge" onclick="window.location.href='/'">Continue</button>
    <button type="submit" class="badge">Info</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```